# Creating new HTML elements in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

enter code hereI have a div that includes three inputs on of this is a file input, I want when the user adds a file another copy of that div appear so that the user can add another file. I want to do it in jquery

I tried the append() event and I copied the HTML code for this div but when the copy appears and the user get to choose another file there is no other copy appears

```
<div class="master-div">
  <div class="divv">
    <input class="click" type="file"> 
   <input type="text">
   <input type="text">
 </div>
</div>
```

```
$('.click').on('click', function () {
        $('.master-div').append('
<div class="divv">
    <input class="click" type="file"> 
   <input type="text">
   <input type="text">
 </div>');


    });
```

Comment: Show us the markup you have and any attempt you have already tried, in the question please.

Comment: You need to share your code but it sounds like an issue with event handlers on dynamic elements. Look at “event delegation” in jQuery to ensure the event handlers applied to dynamically added elements such as these inputs.

Comment: I added the code

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky guessed it. Your `$('.click')` listener is only attached to elements that exist when it's called... future instances of the `.click` elements it creates are not attached to the event listener - hence clicking them does not call the function. Something like `$('.master-div').on('click', '.click', function() { /* CODE HERE */ });` would fix it; this seems to come up every day on this site.

Comment: `$('.divv').on('click', '.click', function () { ...`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In jQuery, how to attach events to dynamic html elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359018/in-jquery-how-to-attach-events-to-dynamic-html-elements)

Comment: It worked, thank you @AlexanderStaroselsky

Comment: It worked, thank you @Taplar

Comment: but is there is a code to copy the HTML just by calling the class instead of writing the HTML code in the JQuery code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your issue is that the click handler is only attached to the `.click` elements that are on the page when the code is run. Attach your handler to `.master-div` and listen for a click on `click`:

```js
$(".master-div").on("click", ".click", function() {
  $('.master-div').append('<div class="divv"><input class="click" type="file"><input type="text"><input type="text"></div>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<div class="master-div">
  <div class="divv">
    <input class="click" type="file">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a well known duplicate.  Vote to close as a duplicate rather than repeating the answer.

Comment: Sorry @Taplar, I didn't know it was a duplicate.

Comment: it worked thank you

Comment: but is there is a code to copy the HTML just by calling the class instead of writing the HTML code in the JQuery code?

Comment: Yes - use `$(".master-div").append($(".diiv").clone(true))`.

Comment: but this copies one copy the first time then 2 then 4 then 8

Comment: @IbrahimYousry `$('.master-div').append($('.divv').first().clone(true));` to just clone the first; otherwise, you're cloning all `.divv` elements and appending them (thus the doubled elements each time).

Comment: Oh yes sorry @mark.hch, forgot about that.